# XCode Implicitly Link Objective-C runtime Library

Tags: xcode

Where is the following linker setting in XCode on Mac OSX

"Implicitly Link Objective-C runtime Library"

It's suppose to be in Project Settings but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Look in build settings for "Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support" instead.

Or filter on "implicit".

(Xcode 9.2)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick reply. Specifically here's now to get to it for Xcode novices like me.

Select View, Navigators, Show Project Navigator.
Then at the top click on the name of the project.
In the middle under Build Settings scroll all the way down to section,
"Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language - Objective C".
Third option is:
"Implicitly Link Objective-C Runtime Support."